# iOS 8 Memory leak using String in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, memory-leaks, ios8

I found the memory leak problem when working with String (NSString) methods for composing and extraction (eg. stringByAppendingPathComponent, lastPathComponent).

I created a sample loop (see code below), and when I run it on the simulator and the device memory is not released. It takes gigabytes! Even after the end of the loop memory does not decrease.

I tried to use autoreleasepool {} without success.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how to remedy this?

I'm working on Xcode 6.3 beta 2, including iOS 8.3 SDK with Swift 1.2

```
func memoryLeakTest() {

    for _ in 1...1000000 {

        let url = NSURL(scheme: "http", host: "google.com", path: "/")!
        let path = url.path
    }
}
```

Example with autoreleasepool:

```
func memoryLeakTest() {

    for _ in 1...1000000 {

        autoreleasepool {

            let url = NSURL(scheme: "http", host: "google.com", path: "/")!
            let path = url.path
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

Problem occurs only on:
- Xcode 6.3 beta 2, including iOS 8.3 SDK with Swift 1.2

Tests performed on the previous versions did not show a problem:
- Xcode 6.2 beta 5, including iOS 8.2 SDK with WatchKit
- Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: Show us how you used `autoreleasepool`.

Comment: Memory might not be cleaned during loop, but should be cleaned after. autoreleasepool should fix the problem, but anyways, why are you creating NSURL every single time, instead of reusing same instance ? What are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: It is just a dummy code to show the problem.

Comment: I just tested your code and didn't see the issue when the loop content was wrapped in `autoreleasepool`

Comment: @blacksquare which Xcode version do you use?

Comment: 6.3. Could it have something to do with the context of memoryLeakTask?

Comment: I don't know, I am looking for the cause of the problem.. I had a suspicion that Apple introduced a change in the autorelease

Comment: this would better asked on the apple forums - apple engineers are quite likely to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring url and path before the loop.

That should then cause it to reuse the same variable and release the previous reference.